# What does distutils do with the "requires" metadata?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

From the [distutils docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages):

> Dependencies on other Python modules and packages can be specified by supplying the `requires` keyword argument to `setup()`.

For example the [python-gflags](https://pypi.org/project/python-gflags/#files) distribution uses `distutils` and specifies a dependency on `six`:

https://github.com/google/python-gflags/blob/master/setup.py#L43

Yet, unlike setuptools' `install_requires` deps, installing python-gflags with pip does not actually install the dependency [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/).

The question is, **what does `distutils` and/or `pip` actually do with this `requires` value**, if anything? I can see it gets stored in the distribution metadata (you can find the requirement specification as plaintext in the file `site-packages/python_gflags-3.1.2.dist-info/METADATA` after installation) but that alone seems useless without a consumer.

Comment: Looking at [PEP 314](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/) (PEP pi?!), it says that [Requires](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/#requires-multiple-use) works in consonance with [Provides](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/#provides-multiple-use)... so, is it possible that something else is "providing" `six` in your case?

Comment: Nothing else is providing six (in a fresh venv with most recent pip, the `import gflags` raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'`).  You're looking at a really old PEP for metadata v1.1 anyway which is now superseded by [metadata v2.1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0566/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through all usages of `requires` in `distutils` I didn't find any meaningful usage except printing this info when running `python setup.py --requires`. On this `setup.py` example:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='foo', requires=['bar', 'baz'])
```

It will show:

```
bar
baz
```

[Source:](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/dist.py#L702)

```
elif opt in ('classifiers', 'provides', 'requires',
             'obsoletes'):
    print('\n'.join(value))
```

Comment: And what about `pip`? Did it ever use that `requires` metadata for anything, historically?

Comment: @wim can't find any usage. List of names in `requires` section is not even displayed by `pip show package_name` - only those which are in `install_requires` are displayed.